# Можно ли прикрутить свою авторизацию на Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows

Простите, но не знаю даже как загуглить такой вопрос(

Вычитал что на Windows 10 Home нельзя поставить Active Directory

У меня возник вопрос, а можно ли поставить свою авторизацию, вместо стандартной?

*не кидайтесь помидорами*

Спасибо за понимание

Comment: В теории возможно всё, но у меня например через ansible для домашней винды дополнительные пользователи не создаются. А на pro - всё ништяк. Так что я бы забил.

Comment: @donRumata ща стукнуло в голову что можно поднять его на Ubuntu Server и тогда нет ни какой проблемы)

Comment: Тогда переформулируй вопрос зачем тебе это всё надо.

Comment: @donRumata Не докупать дополнительно ПО для компании( Я только недавно устроился и ни кто не остановил людей от экономии и закупили винду Home - что уменьшает возможности системы

Comment: Microsoft вроде бы предоставила разработчикам API для смены способов аутентификации. Как вариант использовать 2FA методы, но тогда надо создавать управлять внешними учетками, хранимыми на login.live.com  Если не нравится, то используйте различные биологические считыватели (сканеры отпечатков глаз/пальцев), либо смарт-карты. Если лень разработать такое ПО - купите что-то типа Rohos Login Key. Но если первоочередная задача сэкономить, тогда сочиняйте из того, что под рукой.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел статью которая обходит проблему установкой бесплатной Ubuntu Server на которой можно поднять поддержку централизованного хранения данных учётных записей пользователей и компьютеров.

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/323860/

Думаю это подойдет

Comment: Это конечно да, только хомяка в домен ты ввести всё равно не сможешь. И GPO раскидывать. Контроллер домена - только часть проблемы.